# Deploying images used in Java Application with the built jar file

Tags: java, user-interface, jar

After using images for example on a Button, when I build the application creating the .jar file and execute only the file, the images are not there but would only show if I copy the images folder in the same directory as the jar file. Why is that and how can I resolve this if possible?

I am currently using the following code to set the icon/image:

```
JButton btn = new JButton("Text", "img/icon.png");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that you can use the images when they are stored outside the jar, suggests that you are doing something of the kind:

```
File image = new File("directory/image.jpg");
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(image);
```

This reads a file from a directory on the file system, not from the classpath. Now, if you have packaged your image in a "directory" inside your Jar, you must load the image from the classpath.

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/directory/image.jpg");
```

(note the slash in the path)

Or

```
InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("directory/image.jpg");
```

(note the absence of the slash in the path)

Your example, as it is now, should not compile. (The second argument of your JButton construtor is an Icon, not a String, java 8). So when you were getting the image from the file system, you were probably doing something else.

With your example, you need to read an image from the inputstream and convert it to an Icon:

```
try (InputStream is = getClass.getClassLoader().getResourcesAsStream("directory/image.jpg")) { 
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(is);
    return new JButton("Text", new ImageIcon(image));
} catch (IOException exc) {
    throw new RuntimeException(exc);
}
```

That should use the image that is located in "directory" inside your jar. Of course, you need to include the image within your jar, or you will get a `NullPointerException` on the inputstream `is`.

Comment: I updated the question with a simple example. So if I do it this way, they images will be included in the jar file?

Comment: So if I do this, all images used in the application will be built into the .jar file?

Comment: If you do that, you application wil be able to read the images from within the jar file. But you must still make the jar file, containing the images and your class files.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to understand the

> ClassLoader:
>
> A typical strategy is to transform the name into a file name and then
>   read a "class file" of that name from a file system.

So with this you will be able to lead Resources of your project with `getResource`

> `public URL getResource(String name)`
>
> Finds the resource with the given name. A resource is some data
>   (images, audio, text, etc) that can be accessed by class code in a way
>   that is independent of the location of the code.

Comment: In understand that but that is not the problem. If I want to distribute the application then I'll have to also distribute it with the folder with all the images used in the application which to me does not make much sense.

Comment: How are you loading your imagees in your code? Via ClassLoader ?